# How to show cached data before $timeout complete in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question regarding caching in Angular.
I have the following html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="myApp.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in studentList">
     <name-italic targettext="item">
     </name-italic>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the following javascript file myApp.js

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);

var mainController = myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.studentList = ["sandeep","surabhi","sangeeta","sumant","bapi","ttt","yyy"];
    }, 2000);

});


myApp.run([ '$http', '$templateCache',
function($http, $templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('NAMEITALICTEMPLATE', "<i>{{myText}}</i>");
}]);

myApp.directive("nameItalic",
 ['$templateCache',
 function ($templateCache) {
  return {
      restrict:'E',
      replace:false,
      scope:{
        myText:'=targettext'
      },
      template: $templateCache.get('NAMEITALICTEMPLATE')
    };
}]);
```

The question is why Angular doesn't show cashed data before $timeout complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the timeout there is no such property as `$scope.studentList`, so the `ng-repeat` has nothing to iterate over.

Meaning, directive is not run and template is not fetched.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Omri. 
But is there any way to show cached template for showing second, third... load times, I mean when the template is already cached with it's data. And refresh template after receive new data?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, but you can't load it from the directive since the directive is not loaded. You can add an HTML element like `<div ng-if="!studentList || studentList.length === 0">{{getTemplateFromController()}}</div>` and have an opposite `ng-if` on the `ng-repeat` so their loading will be mutually exclusive.